# how to handle Json Keyerror in Python

Tags: python, json

I have many elements as json Data like this :

```
{
   "listing_1":{
      "general_info":{
         "bedrooms":{
            "value":5
         },
         "bathrooms":{
            "value":4,
         "parking":{
            "value":3
         }
      }
   }
}
```

the problem is the key "general_info" in some elements is missing.
i have tried to implement get() but with no success:

```
beds_number = data["listing_1"].get("general_info", 0)["bedrooms"]["value"]
```

to summurize if the key is missing  i want assign to "beds_number" to "None".

Comment: The json format is incorrect::  "value":4, should be "value":4},

Comment: Please provide examples of possible inputs and corresponding expected outputs.

Comment: .... and include what the output for other attributes (such as "parking") should be when "general_info" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

l think that you cannot do it in one line. Try something like this:

```
beds_number = data["listing_1"]
if "general_info" in beds_number :
    beds_number = beds_number["general_info"]["bedrooms"]["value"]
```

Comment: that may work but the problem is i have many objects other than "general_info", so i have to do this for all of them.